# filter through array values inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects as below, I want to get the whole object where **badge** has **outreach** word. I tried to filter and find but it only give me a single word in the array, not the full object. Please help me sort this out, thanks.

```js
carData: [
  {
    flowName: "Cars",
    badge: ["content", "outreach"],
    image: icons.car,
  },
  {
    flowName: "linkedin",
    badge: ["content"],
    image: icons.linkedin,
  },
  {
    flowName: "facebook",
    badge: ["content"],
    image: icons.facebook,
  },
]
```

This is what I've tried:

```js
console.log(state.carData.map(({badge}) => (badge.filter(i => i==="outreach"))).find(badge=>badge.length>0));
```

It gives the result `['outreach']`.

Comment: Can you please show the filter you attempted?

Comment: yes here it is:

Comment: console.log(state.carData.map(({badge}) => (badge.filter(i => i==="outreach"))).find(badge=>badge.length>0));

Comment: it gives ['outreach']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
carData.filter(x=>x.badge.includes("outreach"))
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for me .... i am new to stack over flow so i can not tickmark it. btw thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
const carData = [{
    flowName: "Cars",
    badge: ["content", "outreach"],
    image: "icons.car",
  },
  {
    flowName: "linkedin",
    badge: ["content"],
    image: "icons.linkedin",
  },
  {
    flowName: "facebook",
    badge: ["content"],
    image: "icons.facebook",
  },
]

console.log(carData.filter(car => car.badge.includes("outreach")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
carData.filter((car) => {
  car.badge.includes("outreach")
})
```